# Using three points to create a quadratic equation produces an equation, which doesn't seem to pass through the original points

Tags: polynomials, quadratics

I've got three (x,y) points from which I am trying to create a quadratic equation, which are:

```
(2325, 5500)
(1880, 3700)
(1400, 2360)
```

Using those three points, I create three simultaneous equations:

```
5500 = 5405625a + 2325b + c
3700 = 3534400a + 1880b + c
2300 = 1960000a + 1400b + c
```

From there, this is the quadratic equation I produce:

```
y = 0.0014x^2 - 1.6524x + 2017.7
```

This seems to be the right equation. In addition, when I generate the equation through Excel and online tools, the same one results. However, when I input the x-values from my original three points, they're all out quite significantly. Compared to the original points, these are the points (using the same x-values) that the equation produces:

```
(2325, 5744)
(1880, 3859)
(1400, 2448)
```

There must be something I have done wrong (and most likely something quite basic) but shouldn't the equation I create from the three points give the correct y-values when I use the same x-values? Can someone please point out to me what is going wrong, and how I can fix it? Thanks!

Comment: It's a rounding error.  Try $0.0013549$ instead of $0.0014$

Comment: Thanks for the quick feedback. I really can't believe I didn't notice that. The x^2 group is going to be the most sensitive to a coefficient change and that is the one that was the most heavily rounded.

Comment: Try to find the exact form of the coefficients if you can. Since this is a linear system with integer inputs, the coefficients must be rational.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're simply using too few significant digits in the most important part, the coefficient $a$:

I have it as $0.0013548942$ to 8sf on an online solver. Note that the error to $0.0014$ is a full $3.3\%$, which is enough to see the deviations in your crosscheck.

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick reply. When I thought it was a basic error, I didn't think it was that basic! I completely understand what you're saying. The the x^2 group is going to be the most sensitive to coefficient changes and that was the one that was most heavily rounded. I just need to stick with using more digits after the decimal place.

Comment: You also got rather unlucky that the 2sf you had were $14$, which is really low ($99$ is the best case), and additionally error is almost maximal in that it's basically $135$ to 3sf - or maybe lucky now that you will have more accurate results after the fix

Answer (score 2):

As long as you can, use whole numbers up to the end.

This would give
$$\left\{a= \frac{2677}{1975800},b= -\frac{652957}{395160},c=
   \frac{6644445}{3293}\right\}$$